Need helping turning points into path curves in a particle system for wind simulations
i'm doing quick wind simulations and as of now my only way of doing it in Blender is using a particle system shown in the screenshots. I'm trying to figure out how to turn these points into curves that immitate the path of these points while retaining the same color (displaying the acceleration of the wind).
I've seen a lot of stuff done with particle nodes but i'm not sure how to retain those color properties based on acceleration


